# Connect and automate Excel table to Outlook Calendar

Tags: python, excel, power-automate, outlook-calendar

so I'm trying to connect and automate an excel timetable to outlook calendar. I will need to update the excel and outlook calendar should automatically update any events as well.

The [excel timetable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EII7s.png) would look something like this.

| Start | End | Itinerary | Participants | Venue/Remark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/18/23 6:00 PM | 8/18/23 7:00 PM | Breakfast | Me |  |
| 8/19/23 6:00 PM | 8/19/23 7:00 PM | Snack Time | Me |  |
| 8/20/23 6:00 PM | 8/20/23 7:00 PM | Lunch | Me |  |
| 8/21/23 6:00 PM | 8/21/23 7:00 PM | Snack Time | Me |  |
| 8/22/23 6:00 PM | 8/22/23 7:00 PM | Dinner | Me |  |
| 8/23/23 6:00 PM | 8/23/23 7:00 PM | Snack Time | Me |  |
| 8/24/23 6:00 PM | 8/24/23 7:00 PM | Exercise | Me |  |

I'm currently using power automate to try this but I have no prior experience with codes so I would like some help.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!